# Seq2SeqLSTM yields the same output with different inputs

Tags: pytorch, time-series, lstm, prediction, seq2seq

I am trying to predict some time series results from experiment data I collected before. Recently I changed to PyTorch from Tensorflow. I am not sure why my results are the same even with different inputs.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ol6W.png)

[Here is a link to my data and code.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1buA-iSR4Xe1iF1xT0L_RrDKTmy95Q32e?usp=sharing)

Or my code is as follows:

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from numpy import array
import numpy as np
import time
import pandas as pd
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torch import nn
import torch
from torch import nn, optim
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

batch_size = 16
num_epochs = 100

# Check if CUDA is available, if not we use CPU
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

start_time_total = time.time()

# per_filename_vec = numpy.array([20, 30, 40, 50])
# Specify the percentage for input data
per_filename = 30

# Read the training and testing data
training_data = pd.read_csv('resampled_training_data.csv').to_numpy()
testing_data = pd.read_csv('resampled_testing_data.csv').to_numpy()

# Calculate the index to split the data into X and y
split_index = int(training_data.shape[1] * per_filename / 100)


def normalize_data(data):
    mean_vals = np.mean(data, axis=1).reshape(-1, 1)
    std_vals = np.std(data, axis=1, ddof=0).reshape(-1, 1)
    standardized_data = (data - mean_vals) / std_vals
    return standardized_data, mean_vals, std_vals


# Normalize training and testing data
X_train, mean_X_train, std_X_train = normalize_data(
    training_data[:, :split_index])
y_train, mean_y_train, std_y_train = normalize_data(
    training_data[:, split_index:])

X_test, mean_X_test, std_X_test = normalize_data(testing_data[:, :split_index])
y_test, mean_y_test, std_y_test = normalize_data(testing_data[:, split_index:])

# Convert to torch tensors and reshape
X_train = torch.from_numpy(X_train.reshape(
    (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))).float()
y_train = torch.from_numpy(y_train.reshape(
    (y_train.shape[0], y_train.shape[1], 1))).float()
X_test = torch.from_numpy(X_test.reshape(
    (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))).float()
y_test = torch.from_numpy(y_test.reshape(
    (y_test.shape[0], y_test.shape[1], 1))).float()

# Move tensors to the device
X_train = X_train.to(device)
y_train = y_train.to(device)
X_test = X_test.to(device)
y_test = y_test.to(device)

# Split your training data into train and validation sets
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(
    X_train, y_train, test_size=0.25, random_state=35)

# Convert your data to TensorDataset
train_data = TensorDataset(X_train, y_train)
val_data = TensorDataset(X_val, y_val)

# Create DataLoaders for your training and validation data
train_loader = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)


class Seq2SeqLSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim, num_layers, dropout):
        super(Seq2SeqLSTM, self).__init__()
        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.output_dim = output_dim

        # Define the LSTM layers with dropout
        self.encoder = nn.LSTM(self.input_dim, self.hidden_dim,
                               self.num_layers, dropout=dropout, batch_first=True)
        self.decoder = nn.LSTM(self.hidden_dim, self.hidden_dim,
                               self.num_layers, dropout=dropout, batch_first=True)

        # Define the output layers
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self.hidden_dim, 50)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(50, self.output_dim)

        # Define the dropout layer
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)

    def forward(self, input):
        # Forward pass through LSTM layer
        lstm_out, _ = self.encoder(input)

        # Repeat the context vector
        lstm_out = lstm_out.repeat(1, input.size(1), 1)

        # Decoder pass
        lstm_out, _ = self.decoder(lstm_out)

        # Only take the output from the final timestep
        lstm_out = lstm_out[:, -1, :]

        # Pass through Dense layers with dropout
        y_pred = self.dropout(F.relu(self.fc1(lstm_out)))
        y_pred = self.fc2(y_pred)

        # Expand dimensions
        y_pred = y_pred.unsqueeze(-1)
        return y_pred


# model = Seq2SeqLSTM(1, 200, output_dim=y_train.shape[1], num_layers=4)
model = Seq2SeqLSTM(
    1, 10, output_dim=y_train.shape[1], num_layers=2, dropout=0.5)
model.to(device)

loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()

# Define the optimizer
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.00025)


# Initialize lists to save the training and validation losses
train_losses = []
val_losses = []

# Initialize total time
total_time = 0

# Training loop
for t in range(num_epochs):
    # Start the timer for each epoch
    epoch_start_time = time.time()

    # Training
    model.train()
    batch_losses = []
    for batch_x, batch_y in train_loader:
        batch_x = batch_x.to(device)  # Move batch data to the device
        batch_y = batch_y.to(device)

        # Forward pass
        y_pred = model(batch_x)  # Use batch data

        # Compute loss
        loss = loss_fn(y_pred, batch_y)  # Use batch data

        # Zero out gradient, else they will accumulate between epochs
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # Backward pass
        loss.backward()

        # Update parameters
        optimizer.step()

        batch_losses.append(loss.item())

    # Save average batch loss for the epoch
    train_losses.append(np.mean(batch_losses))

    # Validation
    model.eval()
    batch_losses = []
    for batch_x, batch_y in val_loader:
        batch_x = batch_x.to(device)  # Move batch data to the device
        batch_y = batch_y.to(device)

        # Forward pass and compute validation loss
        with torch.no_grad():  # Temporarily turn off gradient descent
            y_pred = model(batch_x)
            loss = loss_fn(y_pred, batch_y)

        batch_losses.append(loss.item())

    # Save average batch loss for the epoch
    val_losses.append(np.mean(batch_losses))

    # Calculate elapsed time and total time
    elapsed_time_epoch = time.time() - epoch_start_time
    total_time += elapsed_time_epoch

    # Print progress every 10 epochs
    if t % 10 == 0:
        print(
            f'Epoch {t:<3} | Train Loss: {train_losses[-1]:.8f} | Val Loss: {val_losses[-1]:.8f} | '
            f'Current Elapsed Time: {total_time:.2f} seconds')


# After training, plot the training and validation losses
plt.figure()
plt.plot(train_losses, label='Training Loss')
plt.plot(val_losses, label='Validation Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

batch_size_test = 8


def evaluate(model, test_loader):
    model.eval()  # Set the model to evaluation mode
    test_loss = 0
    num_samples = 0
    with torch.no_grad():  # Temporarily turn off gradient descent
        for X_test, y_test in test_loader:
            X_test = X_test.to(device)  # Move batch data to the device
            y_test = y_test.to(device)

            y_pred = model(X_test)
            # y_pred = y_pred.unsqueeze(-1)

            loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y_test)
            test_loss += loss.item() * X_test.size(0)  # Accumulate the batch loss
            num_samples += X_test.size(0)

    return test_loss / num_samples  # Return average loss


def predict_test_case(model, X_test_case):
    model.eval()  # Set the model to evaluation mode
    with torch.no_grad():
        # add an extra batch dimension and move to device
        X_test_case = X_test_case.unsqueeze(0).to(device)
        y_pred_case = model(X_test_case)
        # remove the extra dimension and squeeze the last dimension
        y_pred_case = y_pred_case.squeeze(0).squeeze(-1)
    return y_pred_case


# Convert your test data to tensor datasets
test_data = TensorDataset(X_test, y_test)

# Create DataLoader for your test data
test_loader = DataLoader(
    test_data, batch_size=batch_size_test, shuffle=False)

# Evaluate the model on the test data
test_loss = evaluate(model, test_loader)
print(f"Average Test loss: {test_loss}")


# -------------------- Calculate R^2 for all test cases -----------------------
# List of test case indices that you want to plot
test_case_indices = np.arange(X_test.shape[0])  # Add more indices as needed

# Create an empty DataFrame to store the results
results_r2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Test Case Index', 'R-squared'])

# Create a list to store all y predictions
all_y_predictions = []

# Loop over each test case
for i, test_case_index in enumerate(test_case_indices):
    # Get the specific test case from X_test and y_test
    x_test_case = X_test[test_case_index]
    y_test_case = y_test[test_case_index]

    # Predict on the test case
    y_pred_case = predict_test_case(model, x_test_case)
    y_pred_case = y_pred_case.cpu().numpy()

    # Store the y prediction in the list
    all_y_predictions.append(y_pred_case)

    # Convert tensor to numpy array for computing R-squared
    y_test_case = y_test_case.cpu().numpy()

    # Calculate R-squared
    r_squared = r2_score(y_test_case, y_pred_case)

    # Add the results to the DataFrame
    results_r2 = pd.concat([results_r2, pd.DataFrame({'Test Case Index': [
                           test_case_index], 'R-squared': [r_squared]})], ignore_index=True)

# Convert the list of all y predictions to a numpy array
all_y_predictions = np.array(all_y_predictions)

# Save the DataFrame to an Excel file
results_r2.to_excel(f'r_squared_results_{per_filename}.xlsx', index=False)


# -------------------------- Plot 4 test cases --------------------------------
# Create a new figure for all subplots
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10, 8))
temp1 = 30
temp2 = (X_test.shape[0]+1)//4
# List of test case indices that you want to plot
test_case_indices = [temp1, temp1+temp2, temp1+2 *
                     temp2, temp1+3*temp2]  # Add more indices as needed

# Loop over each test case
for i, test_case_index in enumerate(test_case_indices):
    # Get the specific test case from X_test
    x_test_case = X_test[test_case_index]
    y_test_case = y_test[test_case_index]

    # Predict on the test case
    y_pred_case = predict_test_case(model, x_test_case)
    y_pred_case = y_pred_case.cpu().numpy()

    # Convert tensor to numpy array for plotting
    x_test_case = x_test_case.cpu().numpy()
    y_test_case = y_test_case.cpu().numpy()

    # Prepare data for plot
    # Combined length of input and output sequences
    time_steps = list(range(len(x_test_case) + len(y_test_case)))
    x_test_steps = time_steps[:len(x_test_case)]
    # Output starts after the input sequence
    y_test_steps = time_steps[len(x_test_case):]

    x_test_case = x_test_case.ravel().tolist()
    y_test_case = y_test_case.ravel().tolist()
    y_pred_case = y_pred_case.ravel().tolist()

    # Compute R-squared
    r_squared = r2_score(y_test_case, y_pred_case)

    # Plot x_test_case in the corresponding subplot
    ax = axs[i // 2, i % 2]
    # ax.plot(x_test_steps, x_test_case, label='Input sequence (x_test)')
    # ax.plot(y_test_steps, y_test_case, label='True output sequence (y_test)')
    ax.plot(y_test_steps, y_pred_case,
            label='Predicted output sequence (y_pred)')

    # Set title and legend for each subplot
    ax.set_title(f'Test Case: {test_case_index}, R^2: {r_squared:.5f}')
    ax.legend()

# Set a shared title for all subplots
fig.suptitle(f'Batch Size: {batch_size}, Epoch: {num_epochs}')

# Adjust spacing between subplots
fig.tight_layout()

# Show the plot
plt.show()

# ------------------------ Denormalize and Store ------------------------------


def denormalize_data(standardized_data, mean_vals, std_vals):
    original_data = (standardized_data * std_vals) + mean_vals
    return original_data


# Denormalize the y predictions
denormalized_y_predictions = denormalize_data(
    all_y_predictions, mean_vals=mean_y_test, std_vals=std_y_test)

# Convert the denormalized y predictions to a DataFrame
denormalized_y_predictions_df = pd.DataFrame(denormalized_y_predictions)

# Generate the file name with 'per_filename' included
file_name = f'denormalized_y_predictions_{per_filename}.csv'

# Save the DataFrame to a CSV file
denormalized_y_predictions_df.to_csv(file_name, index=False)


elapsed_total_time = time.time() - start_time_total
print("------- %s seconds -------" % (elapsed_total_time))
```

I have tried to change hidden unit size, number of layers, learning rate, dropouts. This problem did not exist with Tensorflow.